# jQuery syntax on Twitter Bootstrap JS FILES

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a doubt with the syntax in the  Twitter Bootstrap's JS files. This is an example file (bootstrap-dropdown.js):

```js
!function ($) {

/*  ...    */

  /* APPLY TO STANDARD DROPDOWN ELEMENTS -- QUESTION CODE
   * =================================== */
  $(function () {
    $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
    $('body')
      .on('click.dropdown', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
      .on('click.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
  })

}(window.jQuery);
```

Why they have a code block inside the jQuery function **$(function(){})** ? I think it works without the jQuery function enclosing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This function behaves just like $(document).ready(), in that it should be used to wrap other $() operations on your page that depend on the DOM being ready.

Check the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3).

Comment: so, if I declared this JS FiLE at the end of the BODY, the jQuery function enclosing doesn't have any effect?

Comment: @JoseS **almost** no effect, there may be things that the browser do between the end of `</body>` and the DOM being ready. You should keep it, at least as a security.

Answer (score 1):

```
!function ($) {
    ...
}(window.jQuery);
```

That is used to create a scope (think namespace) who's variables will not pollute the global namespace.

If that would not be used, the `toggle` variable for example, would pollute the global namespace.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm asking about the inner jQuery  function enclosing, after the comment that says "APPLY TO STANDARD DROPDOWN ELEMENTS -- QUESTION CODE"